# Entityframework 4.0 .CreateQuery<T> and OrderBy exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I thought this was fixed in 4.0. I have this method

```
public IQueryable<T> All(Expression<Func<T,object>> sort)
    {
       return EntityContext.CreateQuery<T>(EntityName).AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy(sort);
    }
```

this throws the following exception

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32'
>   to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to
>   Entities only supports casting Entity
>   Data Model primitive types. Source is
>   System.Data.Entity

Any idea how to fix this or if there's any workaround
This happens with every call when the order is not a string datatype

```
IQueryable<Blog> sortedAll = _repository.All(x => x.Title);
```

since Title is a string the orderBy works fine. but it fails with any other datatypes

Since I came up with this "bad" solution before I seen Marc's. I thought I  post it

```
public IQueryable<T> All(Expression<Func<T,object>> sort)
    {

        var expresssionType = sort.Body.GetType();
       string propertyName= expresssionType == typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression) ? ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)sort.Body).Operand).Member.Name : ((MemberExpression)sort.Body).Member.Name;
        var items=   EntityContext.CreateQuery<T>(EntityName).AsQueryable<T>();
        var type = typeof(T);
        var expressionProperty = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        var exPressionparameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(exPressionparameter, expressionProperty);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, exPressionparameter);
        Expression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, expressionProperty.PropertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return items.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't change the runtime, but can't you just work around it? i.e.

```
public IQueryable<T> All<TValue>(Expression<Func<T,TValue>> sort)
{
    return EntityContext.CreateQuery<T>(EntityName)
           .AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T,TValue>(sort);
}
```

and

```
IQueryable<Blog> sortedAll = _repository.All(x => x.SomeProp);
```

?

Comment: Thanks Marc,
Your solution is much better what I came up with.