# EF sorting issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

Have problem with linq expressions.
I want to get from db some data ordered by datetime. Early there was sorting by string field.
Sorting expression (by string):

```
Expression<Func<Matter, Object>> result = e => e.MatterNumber;
//In debug mode: {e => e.MatterNumber}
```

Works fine

Sorting expression (by datetime or int):

```
Expression<Func<Matter, Object>> result = e => e.Created;
//In debug mode: {{e => Convert(e.Created)}}
```

This rise an error: **{"Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."}**

Please help :)

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just using `OrderBy`?

Comment: @James legacy project architecture ;)

Comment: You  might want to tag your question with the .NET framework version you are targeting then. Could you show the full query you are using your expression in?

Comment: @James thank for your suggestion. But I already get an answer. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alexei, you might wanna take a look at this SO Question:

[Entity Framework: LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145847/entity-framework-linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-entity-data-model-primi)

or this one here:

[Help me understand "LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953946/help-me-understand-linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-entity-data-model-pri)

and finally on SO:

[Entityframework 4.0 .CreateQuery<T> and OrderBy exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033787/entityframework-4-0-createqueryt-and-orderby-exception)

and on the forums.asp.net:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1580414.aspx/1

all 4 deal with this issue in slightly differing ways but hopefully will be helpful in your scenario.

Comment: hey alexei - it's a pleasure, i've used those refs before in an EF repository implementation, so thought they may be useful